# Не удается загрузить DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, cmake

Пытаюсь собрать проект через CMake. Проект состоит из C# части (графический интерфейс, exe) и C++ (графический движок, `.dll`).

Сборка проходит успешно, CMake генерирует `.exe` и `.dll` в одну папку.
Но получаю ошибку времени выполнения при загрузке `dll`, а именно:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: "Не удается загрузить DLL "Engine.dll": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Я сначала грешил на отсутствующие связи в библиотеке, посмотрел через Dependencies, все в порядке. С разрядностью библиотеки и `exe` тоже все в порядке, обе x64. В именах экспортируемых методов ошибок нет. Соглашение о вызовах `stdcall`.

Вот код CMake:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
    project(MAIN VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX CSharp)
 
    enable_language(C) 
    enable_language(CXX)
    enable_language(CSharp)
    include(CSharpUtilities)
 
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std:c++latest")
    set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/langversion:latest" )
    set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS} /platform:x64")
 
   file(GLOB EngineFiles "Engine/*.cpp" "Engine/*.h" "Engine/*.hpp")
   add_library(Engine SHARED ${EngineFiles})
 
   find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
   find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED PATHS $ENV{GLFW_INSTALL_DIR})
   find_package(glm REQUIRED)
 
   target_include_directories(Engine PUBLIC ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   target_include_directories(Engine PUBLIC ${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   target_include_directories(Engine PUBLIC ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
 
   target_link_libraries(Engine glfw)
   target_link_libraries(Engine Vulkan::Vulkan)
 
   add_executable(MainApp 
   UI/App.xaml.cs
   UI/App.xaml
   UI/MVVM/SurfaceView/HostSurface.xaml
   UI/MVVM/SurfaceView/HostSurface.xaml.cs
   UI/MVVM/SurfaceView/Win32Host.cs
   UI/MVVM/ViewModels/NewViewModel.cs
   UI/MVVM/ViewModels/Base/ViewModelBase.cs
   UI/MVVM/ViewModels//Commands/RelayCommand.cs
   UI/MVVM/Windows/MainWindow.xaml
   UI/MVVM//Windows/MainWindow.xaml.cs
   UI/3DGraphicsEngine/GraphicsEngine.cs)
 
   csharp_set_xaml_cs_properties(
       App.xaml
    App.xaml.cs
    MainWindow.xaml
    MainWindow.xaml.cs)
 
set_property(SOURCE App.xaml PROPERTY VS_XAML_TYPE "ApplicationDefinition")
set_property(TARGET MainApp PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.8.1")
set_property(TARGET MainApp PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)
set_property(TARGET MainApp PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
    "Microsoft.CSharp"
    "PresentationCore"
    "PresentationFramework"
    "System"
    "System.Core"
    "System.Data"
    "System.Data.DataSetExtensions"
    "System.Net.Http"
    "System.Xaml"
    "System.Xml"
    "System.Windows"
    "System.Windows.Forms.Integration"
    "System.Windows.Forms"
    "System.Printing"
    "System.Reflection.Metadata"
    "System.Xml.Linq"
    "WindowsBase")
```

Вот так я экспортирую метод:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* createGraphicsEngine(HWND hwnd);
```

А вот так импортирую:

```
[DllImport("Engine.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static private extern IntPtr createGraphicsEngine(IntPtr surfaceHandle);
```

Так же хочу заметить, что до этого этот же проект был решением Visual Studio, все работало, разве что путь до библиотеки был "захардкоден", начал переводить все на CMake недавно, собственно и сам CMake изучаю пару дней, что-то упускаю.

Что я делаю не так? В какую сторону думать?

Comment: dll должна лежать в папке с исполняемым exe файлом C# проекта и иметь разрядность как у проекта. Например если dll x64, то и C# проект должен быть явно x64, а не Any CPU. Только в x64 нет никаких stdcall, там только fastcall конвенция, так что скорей всего это x86, следовательно и C# проект надо собрать строго x86.

Comment: Далее, для x86 stdcall это конвенция библиотек Win32 API, и если вы специально не настраивали экспорты на stdcall, то конвенция для C++ по умолчанию cdecl. В общем, вопросов пока больше, чем ответов. Начните со сборки C# проекта под x86, далее попробуйте указать конвенцию cdecl. Либо переходите на x64 и fastcall.

Comment: Я попробовал сделать через fastcall, результат тот же.  Разрядность у dll и exe - X64, проверял через sigcheck. Заметил одну странность: в папке debug, где лежат исполняемый файл и библиотека, есть несколько dll, типа System.Memory.dll , так вот они X32 (sigcheck), разве они не должны быть тоже x64?